# Parse a Dictionary<string, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>> object using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have this dictionary object

```
Dictionary<string, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>
```

Using LINQ method syntax, how to iterate over this object and extract the values if Key="doctype"?

How can I achieved the same result using LINQ?

```
foreach (var type in docuObject.DocuObject)
{
    foreach (var t in type.Value)
    {
        if (t.Key.ToString() == "doctype")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(t.Value.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

[Dictionary object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7h5oo.png)

Comment: i would have left it as xml and used linq to xml

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We could do with a bit of help understanding your question better. If you've already converted the XML into a dictionary, then the XML part is broadly irrelevant. What would be more helpful would be an example *with code* (just hard-code populating the dictionary) and an example of what you want the result to be.

Comment: (I agree with Daniel though that this would be simple to do directly in LINQ to XML. If you need the dictionary very for something else, that's a different matter.)

Comment: Thank you for the replies.. I have multiple types/formats of input sources (each with its own parser) and I think it would be better to have a single data structure (in this case, the Dictionary) that will be consumed by the application. Or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var result = 
  from type in docuObject.DocuObject
  from t in type.Value
  where t.Key == "doctype"
  select t.Value
```

You can then `foreach` over the `result` if you want to write them all to the console.

Answer (score 0):

Easy :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication100
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string STATUS_XML_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test2.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>> dict = doc.Descendants("properties")
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("value"), y => y.Elements("property")
                    .GroupBy(a => (string)a.Attribute("name"), b => (string)b.Attribute("value"))
                    .ToDictionary(a => a.Key, b => b.FirstOrDefault()))
                    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I already created a parser (XML to Dictionary). Now I want to parse this dictionary and I want to try LINQ instead of the traditional nested foreach loops.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was not clear enough. I want to parse the dictionary and not the XML.  I updated the description and provided a screenshot of this dictionary object to avoid confusion. Thanks.